# MouseHover Functionality in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, mousehover

I have created and executed the MouseHover functionality on the **ADD-ONS** tab within https://www.spicejet.com/ but it's not working with the below code.

Can anyone suggest what is missing in the code?

```
package SeleniumExamples;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

public class MouseHoverConcept {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","./driver/chromedriver81.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://www.spicejet.com/");
        // create object for mouse hover
        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"highlight-addons\"]"))).build().perform();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("SpiceMax")).click();
        //driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To demonstrate the *Mouse Hover* functionality using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) on the **ADD-ONS** tab within https://www.spicejet.com/ you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `visibilityOfElementLocated()` and you can use the following  [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code Block:

  ```
  import java.util.Collections;
  import org.openqa.selenium.By;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
  import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
  import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

  public class mouseHover_spicejet_addons {

      public static void main(String[] args) {

          System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\WebDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
          ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
          options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
          options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", Collections.singletonList("enable-automation"));
          options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
          WebDriver driver =  new ChromeDriver(options);
          driver.get("https://www.spicejet.com/");
          WebElement addons = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("a#highlight-addons")));
          new Actions(driver).moveToElement(addons).build().perform();
          new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//ul[@class='add-ons-tab']//li/a[contains(., 'SpiceMax')]"))).click();
      }
  }
  ```
- Browser Snapshot

[image: mousehover]

Answer (score 0):

did you try write it without "build"? :-) If it will not work, are you sure, that xpath is correct?

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"highlight-addons\"]")));
action.perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything is correct. just add the sleep of 10 seconds after the get method like below

```
     driver.get("https://www.spicejet.com/");
     driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
     Thread.sleep(10000);


     // create object for mouse hover
        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='highlight-addons']"))).build().perform();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("SpiceMax")).click();
        //driver.quit();
```

Answer (score 0):

mouseHover is inconsistent in Chrome. You can try JavaScript Executor instead. Below is the code snippet in Java:

```
WebElement elementToHover = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='highlight-addons']"));
String mouseHoverScript = "if(document.createEvent)" +
                "{var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');" +
                "evObj.initEvent('mouseover', true, false); " +
                "arguments[0].dispatchEvent(evObj);} " +
                "else if(document.createEventObject) " +
                "{ arguments[0].fireEvent('onmouseover');}";
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(mouseHoverScript, elementToHover);
```